# C++: String and unions bison

Tags: c++, string, bison, unions

I am building a compiler in flex and bison. The thing is that using `char *` is giving a lot of problems so I'm trying to migrate everything to `string`.

The only problem left is that there is a `union` with strings. I know that this is not a standard, but by using pointers there should be no problem.

Relevant code:

```
#include <string>

using namespace std;

//-- SYMBOL SEMANTIC VALUES -----------------------------
%union {
  struct lc{
     string * code;
     string * start;
     string * verdadero;
     string * falso;
     string * next;
  }code;    
}
```

The weird thing is the error I'm receiving:

```
file.ypp:39:6: error: ‘string’ does not name a type
string * start;
file.ypp:40:6: error: ‘string’ does not name a type
string * verdadero;
file.ypp:41:6: error: ‘string’ does not name a type
string * falso;
file.ypp:42:6: error: ‘string’ does not name a type
string * next;
```

Edit: Forgot to mention that using `std::string` inside the  `union` has the same problem

Comment: possible duplicate of [Bison does not appear to recognize C string literals appropriately](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/699054/bison-does-not-appear-to-recognize-c-string-literals-appropriately)

Comment: @PawełStawarz: I don't see the connection.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that the code in the `%{`...`%}` is only included the `y.tab.c` file generated by bison.  It in NOT included in the `y.tab.h` file.  The `%union` code, on the other hand, IS included in `y.tab.h` (it's part of the `YYSTYPE` definition).  So if your `%union` depends on other declarations, simply putting those declarations (or an `#include`) in `%{`...`%}` won't always work.

Instead, you need to manually insure that those declarations always occur *before* you 
`#include "y.tab.h"` in any other file -- anywhere you have `#include "y.tab.h"` make
 sure you have `#include <string>` (and the `using` if you really want that) before the 
`#include "y.tab.h"` line.  Putting it all in another header file you include is a good option.

Alternately, with bison (but not yacc), you can use `%code requires {`...`}` in the first section of the `.y` file.  Anything in such a block will be copied verbatim into *both* the `y.tab.h` and `y.tab.c` files.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This worked out just fine. Had to `#include <string>` in the `file.tab.hpp`
So, for anyone with the problem:
Compile bison, add the `#include`, compile flex and finally compile the `g++`

Answer (score 4):

You should have a look at Bison 3 and its support for variants.  The following example shows how to store real objects in the stack.

The most important parts to enable variant support are:

```
%define api.value.type variant
...
%token <::std::string> TEXT;
%token <int> NUMBER;
%printer { yyo << $$; } <*>;
%token END_OF_FILE 0;

%type <::std::string> item;
%type <::std::list<std::string>> list;
```

Here is a full example, taken from Bison.

```
%debug
%language "c++"
%defines
%define api.token.constructor
%define api.value.type variant
%define parse.assert
%locations

%code requires // *.hh
{
#include <list>
#include <string>
typedef std::list<std::string> strings_type;
}

%code // *.cc
{
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <sstream>

  // Prototype of the yylex function providing subsequent tokens.
  namespace yy
  {
    static parser::symbol_type yylex ();
  }

  // Printing a list of strings.
  // Koening look up will look into std, since that's an std::list.
  namespace std
  {
    std::ostream&
    operator<< (std::ostream& o, const strings_type& ss)
    {
      o << "(" << &ss << ") {";
      const char *sep = "";
      for (strings_type::const_iterator i = ss.begin(), end = ss.end();
           i != end; ++i)
        {
          o << sep << *i;
          sep = ", ";
        }
      return o << "}";
    }
  }

  // Conversion to string.
  template <typename T>
    inline
    std::string
    string_cast (const T& t)
  {
    std::ostringstream o;
    o << t;
    return o.str ();
  }
}

%token <::std::string> TEXT;
%token <int> NUMBER;
%printer { yyo << $$; } <*>;
%token END_OF_FILE 0;

%type <::std::string> item;
%type <::std::list<std::string>> list;

%%

result:
  list  { std::cout << $1 << std::endl; }
;

list:
  /* nothing */ { /* Generates an empty string list */ }
| list item     { std::swap ($$, $1); $$.push_back ($2); }
;

item:
  TEXT          { std::swap ($$, $1); }
| NUMBER        { $$ = string_cast ($1); }
;
%%

namespace yy
{
  // The yylex function providing subsequent tokens:
  // TEXT         "I have three numbers for you."
  // NUMBER       1
  // NUMBER       2
  // NUMBER       3
  // TEXT         "And that's all!"
  // END_OF_FILE

  static
  parser::symbol_type
  yylex ()
  {
    static int stage = -1;
    ++stage;
    parser::location_type loc(0, stage + 1, stage + 1);
    switch (stage)
      {
      case 0:
        return parser::make_TEXT ("I have three numbers for you.", loc);
      case 1:
      case 2:
      case 3:
        return parser::make_NUMBER (stage, loc);
      case 4:
        return parser::make_TEXT ("And that's all!", loc);
      default:
        return parser::make_END_OF_FILE (loc);
      }
  }

  // Mandatory error function
  void
  parser::error (const parser::location_type& loc, const std::string& msg)
  {
    std::cerr << loc << ": " << msg << std::endl;
  }
}

int
main ()
{
  yy::parser p;
  p.set_debug_level (!!getenv ("YYDEBUG"));
  return p.parse ();
}
```

Bison actually ships with several examples, including in C++.  They should be installed on your machine, see `/usr/local/share/doc/bison/examples/c++` (where `/usr/local` depends on your configuration).

You can browse the C++ examples online on [Savannah](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bison.git/tree/examples/c++) or on [GitHub](https://github.com/akimd/bison/tree/master/examples/c++).

Answer (score 1):

Seems the generated file does not get the namespace. Try using std::string* ... inside the struct lc { } and put the #include  into the right place where it is included into the generated files.

EDIT: your file should look something like that:

```
%{
    #include <string>
%}

%union {
    struct lc{
        std::string * code;
        std::string * start;
        std::string * verdadero;
        std::string * falso;
        std::string * next;
    }code;  
}
```

Comment: I suspect you are likely correct. I'd go even further and recommend breaking the habit of `using namespace std;` altogether. See http://stackoverflow.com/q/1452721/10077

Comment: Wasn't that what I proposed ? Replacing the using namespace std; with explicit std:: scoping of the strings ? :)

Comment: Well, you said, "... inside the struct lc {} ...". I'm suggesting not *ever* using `using namespace std;`. It's a bad habit that can lead to errors that are very difficult to find. See [sbi's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1453605/10077) to the question I linked.

Comment: Sure, I completely agree.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response nh_. Unfortunately I had already tried that and doesn't work. I will  edit the question.