# Strange problem with context free grammar

Tags: parsing, language-design, grammar, bison

I begin with an otherwise well formed (and well working) grammar for a language.  Variables, 
binary operators, function calls, lists, loops, conditionals, etc.  To this grammar I'd like to add what I'm calling the `object` construct:

```
object
  : object_name ARROW more_objects
  ;

more_objects
  : object_name
  | object_name ARROW more_objects
  ;

object_name
  : IDENTIFIER
  ;
```

The point is to be able to access scalars nested in objects.  For example:

```
car->color
monster->weapon->damage
pc->tower->motherboard->socket_type
```

I'm adding `object` as a `primary_expression`:

```
primary_expression
  : id_lookup
  | constant_value
  | '(' expression ')'
  | list_initialization
  | function_call
  | object
  ;
```

---

Now here's a sample script:

```
const list = [ 1, 2, 3, 4 ];
for var x in list {
  send "foo " + x + "!";
}
send "Done!";
```

Prior to adding the nonterminal `object` as a `primary_expression` everything is sunshine and puppies.  Even after I add it, Bison doesn't complain.  No shift and/or reduce conflicts reported.  And the generated code compiles without a sound.  But when I try to run the sample script above, I get told `error on line 2: Attempting to use undefined symbol '{' on line 2.`

If I change the script to:

```
var list = 0;
for var x in [ 1, 2, 3, 4 ] {
  send "foo " + x + "!";
}
send "Done!";
```

Then I get `error on line 3: Attempting to use undefined symbol '+' on line 3.`

Clearly the presence of `object` in the grammar is messing up how the parser behaves [SOMEhow], and I feel like I'm ignoring a rather simple principle of language theory that would fix this in a jiff, but the fact that there aren't any shift/reduce conflicts has left me bewildered.

Is there a better way (grammatically) to write these rules?  What am I missing?  Why aren't there any conflicts?

(And here's the [full grammar file](http://code.google.com/p/symphonymud/source/browse/branches/development/muscl/src/muscl/muscl.y?r=466#264) in case it helps)

---

**UPDATE:** To clarify, this language, which compiles into code being run by a virtual machine, is embedded into another system - a game, specifically.  It has scalars and lists, and there are no complex data types.  When I say I want to add `object`s to the language, that's actually a misnomer.  I am not adding support for user-defined types to my language.

The objects being accessed with the `object` construct are actually objects from the game which I'm allowing the language processor to access through an intermediate layer which connects the VM to the game engine.  This layer is designed to decouple as much as possible the language definition and the virtual machine mechanics from the implementation and details of the game engine.

So when, in my language I write:

```
player->name
```

That only gets codified by the compiler.  "player" and "name" are not traditional `identifier`s because they are not added to the symbol table, and nothing is done with them at compile time except to translate the request for the name of the player into 3-address code.

Comment: I'd replace the definition of object with "object: primary_expression '->' id_lookup".

Comment: @Ira Baxter: That would work (as far as fixing the problem), but it's not what I'm looking to do because the tokens in each object aren't normal identifiers.

Comment: @Chris: OK, how about "object: primary_expression '->' object_name" with the addition of "object_name" to your original definition of "primary_expression" [Why aren't object identifiers lexically identical to other identifiers?  People have generally given up making category-specific identifiers special]

Comment: @Ira Baxter: object identifiers ARE lexically identical to other identifiers - but semantically they're different.  Object identifiers don't get stored in the symbol table and aren't processed (other than being parsed and set aside) by the compiler.  They're simply stored into the 3-address code, and it's the VM that processes them in a special fashion at runtime.

Comment: @Chris: if object ids are lexically identical, then my first suggestion IMHO is by far the right one.  The task you set out is *parsing*, where presumably you want to build an AST representing your program.  You can handle code generation post-parsing, including any issues about whether an id is a "variable" or an "object".   (If you are trying to build an on-the-(parse)-fly code generator, maybe you have an argument but in general you don't want to tangle parsing and semantic analysis).

Comment: @Ira Baxter: Lexically identical (meaning the same to the lexer) but again, not semantically identical (meaning they're different entities to the parser).  Your original suggestion would lead to the validity of expressions like `do_something()->stuff` which is illegal.

Comment: @Chris:  Do you really want to reject  do_something()->stuff?  Imagine that do_something returns an object (reference).

Comment: @Chris: I've read your clarification as to your purpose.  OK,so my second suggestion should have worked.

Comment: @Ira Baxter: I do want to reject `do_something()->stuff` because while these object identifiers aren't traditional identifiers, they aren't completely, ignored either.  At compile time, the compiler queries the intermediate layer to make sure that the tokens it's codifying for the VM will be valid at runtime.  So while it might be nice to say `return_a_string()->attribute_name`, that could very well lead to runtime errors if the value returned by `return_a_string` is not a valid object identifier.

Comment: @Ira Baxter: While, like I've said, `object: primary_expression '->' object_name` would create an error-free parser, it would not enable a means to the end I'm seeking.  I'm quite certain that the methodology I have (conceptually) is what I want - I just can't figure out, grammatically, why the generated parser is acting out.

Comment: When I look at your grammar at line 264, you define the syntax for an object... but you don't appear to create a tree for object subexpression. What do expect the primary_expression rule to do when it encounters an object and tries to set $$ to what I am guess ing is <junk>?

Comment: @Ira Baxter: I left out the production rules for the sake of example.

Comment: @Chris: Oh.  Well, when you exhibit code like this you really should mark parts you deleted with something clear, like *semantic action deleted* so we don't distracted by red herrings.  In any case, see my *left* recursive answer.

Comment: Is there any chance of getting the code for the lexical analyzer, so we can hack on the grammar without having to put the work in on the analyzer?  I would have gone further but decided I couldn't justify the time spent on doing a lexical analyzer for this (or I'm too lazy, or I've forgotten how easy it would really be with lex/flex, or ...).  It should be standalone-compilable - either you supply the headers etc it needs, or it is written so it only needs standard C libraries around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I spent a reasonable amount of time picking over the grammar (and the bison output) and can't see what is obviously wrong here.  Without having the means to execute it, I can't easily figure out what is going on by experimentation.  Therefore, here are some concrete steps I usually go through when debugging grammars.  Hopefully you can do any of these you haven't already done and then perhaps post follow-ups (or edit your question) with any results that might be revealing:

1. Contrive the smallest (in terms of number of tokens) possible working input, and the smallest possible non-working inputs based on the rules you expect to be applied.
2. Create a copy of the grammar file including only the troublesome rules and as few other supporting rules as you can get away with (i.e. you want a language that only allows construction of sequences consisting of the `object` and `more_object` rules, joined by ARROW.  Does this work as you expect?
3. Does the rule in which it is nested work as you expect?  Try replacing `object` with some other very simple rule (using some tokens not occuring elsewhere) and seeing if you can include those tokens without it breaking everything else.
4. Run bison with `--report=all`.  Inspect the output to try to trace the rules you've added and the states that they affect.  Try removing those rules and repeat the process - what has changed?  This is extremely time consuming often, and is a giant pain, but it's a good last resort.  I recommend a pencil and some paper.

Looking at the structure of your error output - '+' is being recognised as an identifier token, and is therefore being looked up as a symbol.  It might be worth checker your lexer to see how it is processing identifier tokens.  You might just accidentally be grabbing too much.  As a further debugging technique, you might consider turning some of those token literals (e.g. '+', '{', etc) into real tokens so that bison's error reporting can help you out a little more.

EDIT: OK, the more I've dug into it, the more I'm convinced that the lexer is not necessarily working as it should be.  I would double-check that the stream of tokens you are getting from yylex() matches your expectations before proceeding any further.  In particular, it looks like a bunch of symbols that you consider special (e.g. '+' and '{') are being captured by some of your regular expressions, or at least are being allowed to pass for identifiers.

Comment: I'll certainly try some of these (thanks for the --report=all comment; didn't know about that) but I have done a little research already.  One I think telling caveat of this bug is that if I change `object: object_name ARROW more_objects;` to `object: '$' object_name ARROW more_objects;` then everything works fine.  In other words, when the FIRST of `object` isn't `IDENTIFIER` there is no problem.  I feel like it provides valuable insight even if I don't know what yet.

Comment: If you substitute object_name for id_lookup, do you start getting shift/reduce conflicts?

Comment: No change in behavior when I swap `object_name` for `id_lookup`

Comment: Hang on a second... you say you've looked at "the bison output" - what do you mean?  I think it's worth clarifying that the error output ("Attempting to use undefined symbol '+' on line 3.") is coming from my parser when I run the script, not from Bison processing the .y file.

Comment: Yes, I guessed that.  That output is generated when the id_lookup production rule fails, correct?  This means that the symbol "+" is ending up being looked up by id_lookup. I also took the linked grammar file and ran it through bison with the various reporting levels turned on.  I couldn't see anything obviously wrong in that output.  Have you manually verified that the tokens coming out of your lexer are correct as a first step? Do a little wrapper main() that just calls yylex() and spits out the tokens. If that output is actually correct, then perhaps you could post that output for us?

Comment: @Chris: I second Gian's suggestion. Verify your lexer produces the tokens you think it should, before you decide the parser is ill.  The bit about "+" being diagnosed by id_lookup is pretty suspicious.

Answer (score 2):

It seems you are doing a classical error when using direct strings in the yacc source file. Since you are using a lexer, you can only use token names in yacc source files. [More on this here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/517113/lisp-grammar-in-yacc/520268#520268)

Comment: Actually this method has been working just fine, but I'd been wondering whether it was poor practice.  At any rate, it has no impact on the problem at hand.

Answer (score 1):

I think your principal problem is that you failed to define a subtree constructor
in your object subgrammar.  (EDIT: OP says he left the semantic actions for
**object** out of his example text.   That doesn't change the following answer).

You probably have to lookup up the objects in the order encountered, too.
Maybe you intended:

```
primary_expression 
   : constant_value                                        { $$ = $1; } 
   | '(' expression ')'                                    { $$ = $2; } 
   | list_initialization                                   { $$ = $1; } 
   | function_call                                         { $$ = $1; } 
   | object                                                { $$ = $1; } 
   ; 



object
   : IDENTIFIER    { $$ = LookupVariableOrObject( yytext ); } 
   |  object ARROW IDENTIFIER  { $$ = LookupSubobject( $1, yytext ); } 
   ;
```

I assume that if one encounters an identifier X by itself, your default interpretation
is that it is a variable name.  But, if you encounter  X -> Y, then even if X
is a variable name, you want the *object* X with subobject Y.

What LookupVarOrObject does is to lookup the *leftmost* identifier encountered to see if it is variable
(and return essentially the same value as idlookup which must produce an AST node of type AST_VAR), 
or see if it is valid object name, and return an AST node marked as an AST_OBJ,
or complain if the identifier isn't one of these.

What LookupSuboject does, is to check its left operand to ensure it is an AST_OBJ
(or an AST_VAR whose name happens to be the same as that of an object).
and complain if it is not.  If it is, then its looks up the yytext-child object of
the named AST_OBJ.

EDIT: Based on discussion comments in another answer, right-recursion in the OP's original
grammar might be problematic if the OP's semantic checks inspect global lexer state (yytext).
This solution is left-recursive and won't run afoul of that particular trap.

Answer (score 1):

You don't get shift/reduce conflicts because your rules using `object_name` and `more_objects` are right-recursive - rather than the left-recursive rules that Yacc (Bison) handles most naturally.

On classic Yacc, you would find that you can run out of stack space with deep enough nesting of the '`object->name->what->not`' notation.  Bison extends its stack at runtime, so you have to run out of memory, which is a lot harder these days than it was when machines had a few megabytes of memory (or less).

One result of the right-recursion is that no reductions occur until you read the last of the object names in the chain (or, more accurately, one symbol beyond that).  I see that you've used right-recursion with your `statement_list` rule too - and in a number of other places too.

Comment: You'll run out of stack space only if it right recurses a huge number of times, unless your stack is rediculously small.  No human being will code a->b->...->z for a very long chain, so I just don't see how that can be a practical objection.

Comment: Right reductions shouldn't prevent him from getting a working result.  I personally prefer left recursive lists because they "feel" better and they are a tiny bit more efficient, but that's just personal bias and not a technical issue.

Comment: @Ira: agreed - right reduction doesn't prevent the grammar working.  In classic Yacc, you could run out of right-recursive stack relatively quickly (150 or so), but I agree it is not a practical objection.  What is a factor, though, is that the lexer has to read much further before anything can be reduced, and the symptoms of the trouble could be related to that - if the symbols are not saved correctly as they are read.  Yacc deals in LALR(1) grammars - Look Ahead Left-Right grammars with 1 token of look-ahead.

Comment: His tokens aren't ambiguous, so it doesn't matter how far ahead the lexer gets as long as every lexeme carries its complete state. However, if he expects to test the state of yytext on an early token, and yytext is a global variable overwritten by the most recent collected token, *then* he could have problem with a right recursive rule, I'll agree. If that's his problem, though, the disease is caused by each lexeme not carrying its entire state, e.g., he's being hurt by his lexer/parser generator. That would be a real shame and he'd still have to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

id_lookup 
   : IDENTIFIER

is formally identical to

object_name 
   : IDENTIFIER

and object_name would accept everything that id_lookup wouldn't, so assertLookup( yytext ); probably runs on everything that may look like IDENTIFIER and is not accepted by enother rule just to decide between the 2 and then object_name can't accept because single lookahead forbids that.

For the twilight zone, the two chars that you got errors for are not declared as tokens with opends the zone of undefinded behavior and could trip parser into trying to treat them as potential identifiers when the grammar gets loose.

Answer (score 0):

I just tried running muscl in Ubuntu 10.04 using bison 2.4.1 and I was able to run both of your examples with no syntax errors. My guess is that you have a bug in your version of bison. Let me know if I'm somehow running your parser wrong. Below is the output from the first example you gave.

`./muscle < ./test1.m (this was your first test)`

```
\-statement list
  |-declaration (constant)
  | |-symbol reference
  | | \-list (constant)
  | \-list
  |   |-value
  |   | \-1
  |   |-value
  |   | \-2
  |   |-value
  |   | \-3
  |   \-value
  |     \-4
  |-loop (for-in)
  | |-symbol reference
  | | \-x (variable)
  | |-symbol reference
  | | \-list (constant)
  | \-statement list
  |   \-send statement
  |     \-binary op (addition)
  |       |-binary op (addition)
  |       | |-value
  |       | | \-foo 
  |       | \-symbol reference
  |       |   \-x (variable)
  |       \-value
  |         \-!
  \-send statement
    \-value
      \-Done!

 +-----+----------+-----------------------+-----------------------+
 |   1 | VALUE    | 1                     |                       |
 |   2 | ELMT     | @1                    |                       |
 |   3 | VALUE    | 2                     |                       |
 |   4 | ELMT     | @3                    |                       |
 |   5 | VALUE    | 3                     |                       |
 |   6 | ELMT     | @5                    |                       |
 |   7 | VALUE    | 4                     |                       |
 |   8 | ELMT     | @7                    |                       |
 |   9 | LIST     |                       |                       |
 |  10 | CONST    | @10                   | @9                    |
 |  11 | ITER_NEW | @11                   | @10                   |
 |  12 | BRA      | @14                   |                       |
 |  13 | ITER_INC | @11                   |                       |
 |  14 | ITER_END | @11                   |                       |
 |  15 | BRT      | @22                   |                       |
 |  16 | VALUE    | foo                   |                       |
 |  17 | ADD      | @16                   | @11                   |
 |  18 | VALUE    | !                     |                       |
 |  19 | ADD      | @17                   | @18                   |
 |  20 | SEND     | @19                   |                       |
 |  21 | BRA      | @13                   |                       |
 |  22 | VALUE    | Done!                 |                       |
 |  23 | SEND     | @22                   |                       |
 |  24 | HALT     |                       |                       |
 +-----+----------+-----------------------+-----------------------+
foo 1!
foo 2!
foo 3!
foo 4!
Done!
```